# django - How to make a simple shopping cart

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm at a loss. I've searched most of the links on Google/YouTube and can't seem to figure out how to create a simple session-based cart in Django!

My website is NOT an e-commerce store. I have a Post model which users can review via a Comment model. They review the Post's overall quality, overall difficulty, and workload based on a 1-5 rating system.

All that I want is for users to be able to go to the Post page, press "Add to Cart" and be redirected to a "cart.html" page where they see the Post they just added, as well as that Post's ratings (Quality, Difficulty, Workload). These ratings come from my Comment model, which is 100% based on User input.

I need this cart to exist in the session! It is very important that anonymous users have access to this feature.

here's a brief snippet of my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    [...]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    # rest of code

class Comment(models.Model):
    [...]
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="usernamee")
    [...]
    overall_rating = models.FloatField(choices=overall_rating_choices, 
    default=None)
    difficulty_rating = models.FloatField(choices=difficulty_rating_choices, default=None)
    workload_rating = models.FloatField(choices=workload_rating_choices, 
    default=None)

    # rest of code
```

I don't need a checkout page, I don't need any payment processing, I don't need any price calculations for any of my posts and I don't need quantities at all. Each post should only be added once and that's it.

This is a special use case and I'm afraid my Django skills aren't up to par to tackle this yet.

I would ask if anybody can give me some sort of guidance on this issue?

P.S. I have been doing Django for 2 months now. I'd say my skill level is at about a 2/10.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've shown your models, this needs to be done in the view. You're probably confusing yourself by talking about a shopping cart; in fact all you need is the ability to add things to the session, which is fully explained in the session docs.

Comment: I added my models to show the relationship between "overall_rating", "difficulty_rating", and "workload_rating" and how they relate to Post. Since I need those values to show up in my "cart.html" page. I am currently reading the docs for Django since I seem to have exhausted all other options that specifically talk about a cart. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You just need in some view add a value in a session object and you will able to see this value in every place in your app so read here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#session-object-guidelines